# Show that $\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(\tanh x) = \operatorname{sech}(2x)$

Tags: calculus

Show that $\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(\tanh(x)) = \operatorname{sech}(2x)$¨

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(\tanh(x))=\frac{1}{1+(\tanh(x))^2}
\frac{d}{dx}\tanh(x)$$

$$=\frac{\operatorname{sech}^2(x)}{1+\tanh^2x}=\frac{\frac{1}{\cosh^2(x)}}{\frac{1+(\sinh^2x)}{\cosh^2x}}$$

at this point the $\cosh^2x$ should cancel themselves out but that leaves me without the ability to show that $\frac{d}{dx} \arctan(\tanh(x)) = \operatorname{sech}(2x)$

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check your denominator's denominator in that last expression.

Comment: It's correct. The $cosh^2(x)$ are both in the denominators in the numerator fraction and the denominator fraction.

Comment: $$1+\tanh^2 x=1+{\sinh^2 x\over\cosh^2 x}={\cosh^2 x+\sinh^2 x\over\cosh^2 x}\ne {1+\sinh^2 x\over \cosh^2 x}$$

Comment: Where is the derivative for $tanh(x)^2$? Recall: $\frac{d}{dx}arctan(g'(x))$

Comment: I'm just commenting on your denominator, not the whole problem.

Comment: See also [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function).